# Solr 7.3 Facet count not correct when group

Tags: solr

I'm grouping my search results by a TopicID field from my result set.

But when I do that the Facet count is using the total number of matches for that Facet and not grouping them. Is it possible to display the total number of groups and not documents it matches?

I try setting the group.facet to true but when I do that I do not get any results I get an error.

Here is my query setup

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/topics/select?defType=edismax&group.field=topic_id&group=true&q=Lens&qf=topic_id%20topic_title%20post_text%20userNameSearch^5&rows=2
```

That will return 10,770 documents in 3,066 groups

On my userName Facet I have 
Username 1 (10,840)
Username 2 (374)
....

When I filter on Username 1 I get 575 groups that contains 10,840 documents on it.

I'm trying to display the correct number of group on the Facet and not the total documents.

When I add `group.facet=true` I get the following error message

```
"error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.lang.IllegalStateException"],
    "msg":"Exception during facet.field: userName",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception during facet.field: userName\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.lambda$getFacetFieldCounts$0(SimpleFacets.java:840)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets$3.execute(SimpleFacets.java:773)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getFacetFieldCounts(SimpleFacets.java:849)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent.getFacetCounts(FacetComponent.java:329)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent.process(FacetComponent.java:273)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:295)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:195)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:711)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:517)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:384)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:330)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1629)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NUMERIC for field 'topic_id' (expected=SORTED). Re-index with correct docvalues type.\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.checkField(DocValues.java:340)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getSorted(DocValues.java:392)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.grouping.TermGroupFacetCollector$SV.doSetNextReader(TermGroupFacetCollector.java:146)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.SimpleCollector.getLeafCollector(SimpleCollector.java:33)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:651)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:462)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getGroupedCounts(SimpleFacets.java:723)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getTermCounts(SimpleFacets.java:497)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getTermCounts(SimpleFacets.java:426)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.lambda$getFacetFieldCounts$0(SimpleFacets.java:834)\r\n\t... 45 more\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

Comment: What is the type of the topic_id field? The exception message is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NUMERIC for field 'topic_id' (expected=SORTED). Re-index with correct docvalues type.". My initial guess is that the field you're using for grouping has to be a strfield.

Comment: topic_id is a pint. <field name="topic_id" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>. I will copy the field to a string field and try use that for the grouping.

Answer (score -1):

whenever you pass query for group for specific field it will return total number document matched count.

But if you want to get the total number of groups in response along with document matches pass below extra parameter.

```
&group.ngroups=true
```

If you pass above parameter in your then you also get the number of group count in response.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/topics/select?defType=edismax&group.field=topic_id&group=true&q=Lens&qf=topic_id%20topic_title%20post_text%20userNameSearch^5&rows=2&group.ngroups=true
```

you will get below resposen,

```
grouped: {
 ssub_chain: {
 matches: 4,
 ngroups: 4,
  groups: [
   {
    groupValue: "Momo Junction_10869",
    doclist: {},
   },
   {..},
   {..},
   {..},
  ],
}
},
```

Comment: But that is not what the user is asking - this is a question about generating facets for each group, not about the number of groups.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh, I am just trying to the ans for question he asked. please find below user question.
Is it possible to display the total number of groups and not documents it matches ?

Comment: I was talking about the Facet count, the facet count was not display the numbers of groups it matched, it is displaying the numbers of documents it matched.

Comment: So to group your fields you would have add the following parameters to your search request:
       group=true         // Enables grouping
       group.facet=true   // Facet counts to be number of groups instead of 
       documents
       group.field=Store  // Groups results by the field "Store"
       group.ngroups=true // Tells Solr to return the number of groups found


The number of groups found is what you would show to the user and use for paging, instead of the normal total count, which would be the total number of documents in the index.

Hope it works for you